# How to trim space after the string?

Tags: xcode4.2

In my program, I need the users to answer the questions. However, if the users typed several spaces after typing the string, how can I eliminate all the spaces after the string in order to compare the answer correctly? I just know the method to trim one space after the string only. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Which language would the program be written in?

Comment: @larsmans given the `xcode4.2` tag, I would infer Objective-C.

Comment: You can edit your question to add the language you're using - both in the description and in the **tags**, the later will help people find your question.

Answer (score 0):

[Read the manual.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Write the code.

```
NSString* trimmed = [mystring stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: I have used the method mentioned before. However, if i typed the space key for more than one times, than the answer became incorrect.